# Setting the labels of a chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I copy this example from matplotlib site and now I want to change the font, color and size of the labels, but not the numbers size. And there is a possiblity to just see the numbers that are in the middle and at the end of each side?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:6*np.pi:0.25, 0:4*np.pi:0.25]
Z = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.cos(X) + np.cos(Y)))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X + 1e5, Y + 1e5, Z, cmap='autumn', cstride=2, rstride=2)
ax.set_xlabel("X-Label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y-Label")
ax.set_zlabel("Z-Label")
ax.set_zlim(0, 2)

plt.show()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size, color and type by setting [text properties](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html) when you create the label like this:

```
ax.set_xlabel("X-Label", size  = 40, color = 'r', family =  'fantasy')
```

You can control which tick marks are displayed using [ax.set_xticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html).

Comment: In general it is better to use Locators than to set the tick locations by hand.

Comment: What are the locators?? I haven't used. How can I only consider the values in the middle and on the tops? For not having a lot of numbres over the axes.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating  `ax.get_yaxis().get_major_locator().set_params(nbins=3)` will get you three ticks. (edit, spelling)